# Is there a way to shatter objects in Unity? (by dividing original mesh)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my actual work I'm importing an object that is already shattered via Blender, however I'm looking for a way to import an intact model and then shatter it, or even divide it, right in Unity, via some script.

Like for instance let's say that with a click I want this object to explode in X pieces.
The small objects have to be interactable, I need to grab them and use them.
Is there a way to do this right inside Unity or I'm "stuck" with using Blender for shatter the object?

Comment: For exploding objects, you just "Hide" your imported object and use particles to do this job for you. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ParticleSystems.html

Comment: I guess I missed some information, but I want the small pieces to be interactable. I'm going to edit the question, but thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your model mesh in Unity3D or create new mesh via script so you can do what you want in Unity3D. This is however not the easiest and best performance wise due to necessary calculations especially if the mesh is complex.

From Unity3D [documentation on Procedural Mesh Geometry:](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GeneratingMeshGeometryProcedurally.html)

> The Mesh
>    class gives script access to an object’s mesh geometry, allowing meshes to be created or modified at runtime. This technique is useful for graphical effects (eg, stretching or squashing an object) but can also be useful in level design and optimisation.

I think in most cases what you want is done with premade set of prefabs.

Comment: Do you know any tutorials about those mesh calculations?
What do you mean by "premade set of prefabs"?

Comment: You can check my edited answer for Unity documentation where you can learn quite a bit. There are tons of materials online regarding mesh creation and manipulation.

Comment: What I mean with "premade set of prefabs" is that its better to create few versions of your object in blender, import it to Unity and then instantiate the one you need (version split into 5, version split into 10... etc). This solution is easier and better for performance.

Comment: Ah yes, I already have objects that are shattered, and that works well, but I thought that there would be a way to do that directly in Unity.
I will try with the mesh manipulation, but I0m worring about the performance topic, since I will use objects with a high polygon count.